# "No functional enrichment retrieved possibly due to an error" with StringApp 1.5.0 and Cytoscape 3.7.2

Tags: cytoscape

I am new here and trying to get around functional enrichment using StringApp (1.5.0) and Cytoscape (3.7.2). I am following the available tutorial https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape-tutorials/protocols/differentially-expressed-genes/#/8, but I always get the error message that "Enrichment retrieval returned no results, possibly due to an error" in Cytoscape. I have tried with another tutorial dataset, still get the same issue.

Anyone who can help?

Thank you!
Mélanie

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error today too. Retrieving proteins in Cytoscape through the String app still works fine, it seems to be related specifically to functional enrichment.